# Ubuntu 14.04 running slow on Dell Vostro 1440

Tags: performance, dell-vostro

I am using a Dell Vostro 1440, with Intel(R) Celeron(R) CPU P4600 processor size: 1995MHz,capacity: 1995MHz, 2GB RAM.

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64-bit. It is running too slow. I want to know whether I am using the right OS for my system specification, and if so, how I can improve performance.

Comment: I'd guess your 2GB RAM are the bottleneck. 2GB is quite few nowadays. I guess you installed vanilla Ubuntu with Unity desktop, but you should rather decide on a desktop environment that is more lightweight, like LXDE (comes with Lubuntu) or XFCE (comes with Xubuntu).

Comment: i am using Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS "Trusty Tahr" - Release amd64